# Assign value sequentially using ansible

Tags: ansible, sequence

I want to assign a value to a variable in a sequential order. The first time I run the playbook I wanted to assign 103 to a variable, the next time it should be 104. I also need to make sure the value assigned is not in the list.

Variables:

```
list1: 
 - 100
 - 101
 - 102

val: 100
```

Playbook:

```
  - name: Set fact
    set_fact:
      val: "{{ val | int + 1 }}"
    until: val not in list1
```

It tried three times and failed with the below error.

> FAILED - RETRYING: Set xxx (1 retries left).
> fatal: [xxx.com]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"val": "102"}, "attempts": 3, "changed": false}

I have also tried with_sequence, but it assigns 100 values and finally the value will be 200, it doesn't exit after just assigning the first value. Is there a way for this?

```
with_sequence: start=100 end=200
until: val not in list1
```

Please advise.

Comment: `"{{ list1 | max +1 }}"` ?

Comment: I would guess one would want `run_once: yes` on that `set_fact:` task, too, in order to prevent _every_ host in the play from executing that

Comment: @Zeitounator the list mght have other values also. I need to assign from 100 onwards,cannot take max from the list.

Comment: Can you tell me what is wong with this until statement? i tried with retries: 6 as well, still it fails

Comment: What is wrong: retry / until applies to a task When using loop, it applies to a single iteration. You could use this for example to call a uri for a list of ids until each corresponding job id in your loop returns 'done'. In your case, your are basically retrying X times to test if the first value is not in the list and fail. You do not need a loop to do this. See my answer. I also strongly suggest you have a look at custom filters if you have other requirements like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably create a custom filter for that but here is a way to do this directly in ansible. I am passing the existing values as an extra comma delimited value on the command line for easy testing.

The idea:

- create a sequence starting at beginning of occupied slots and ending 1 number after the last.
- subtract the existing values from that sequence.
- take the lower value in the resulting list.

Here is the example playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Find next available slot in a range
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    occupied_slots: "{{ existing.split(',') | map('int') }}"

    range_start: "{{ occupied_slots | min }}"

    range_end: "{{ occupied_slots | max + 2 }}"

    next_available: "{{ (range(range_start | int, range_end | int)) | difference(occupied_slots) | min }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Show next available slot
      debug:
        msg: "{{ next_available }}"
```

Which gives:

```
# Pass a contiguous list
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e existing=100,101,102

PLAY [Find next available slot in a range] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show next available slot] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "103"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

# Pass a list containing holes
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e existing=100,101,102,103,105

PLAY [Find next available slot in a range] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show next available slot] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "104"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```